# Ruby on rails - PUT method on update ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby, controller

Could someone tell me why this PUT method doesn't work please.

```
$.ajax({
        type: "PUT",
        dataType: "script",
        url: '/resources/35',
        data:
        {
            resource : { pos_y: 45, pos_x: 50 }
        }
    }).done(function( msg )
            {
                alert( "Data Saved: " + msg );
            });
```

Server says that I have used the **GET method** but in my ajax request I have **type: "PUT"**

```
Started GET "/resources/35?resource%5Bpos_y%5D=45&resource%5Bpos_x%5D=50&_=1344001820350" for 192.168.1.89 at 2012-08-03 15:50:20 +0200
Processing by ResourcesController#show as */*
  Parameters: {"resource"=>{"pos_y"=>"45", "pos_x"=>"50"}, "_"=>"1344001820350", "id"=>"35"}
  User Load (0.3ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" 
  Resource Load (0.1ms)  SELECT "resources".* FROM "resources" WHERE "resources"."id" = ? LIMIT 1  [["id", "35"]]
  Rendered resources/show.html.erb within layouts/login (2.3ms)
Completed 200 OK in 238ms (Views: 235.9ms | ActiveRecord: 0.4ms)
```

resources_controller.rb

```
 # PUT /resources/1                                                                                                                                                             
  # PUT /resources/1.json                                                                                                                                                        
  def update
    @resource = Resource.find(params[:id])

    respond_to do |format|
      if @resource.update_attributes(params[:resource])
        format.html { redirect_to @resource, notice: 'successfully updated.' }
        format.js
      else
        format.html { render action: "edit" }
        format.js
      end
    end
  end
```

I have tried adding **_method: 'put'** But it's still the same

```
$.ajax({
        type: "PUT",
        dataType: "script",
        url: '/resources/35',
        data:
        {
            resource : { pos_y: 45, pos_x: 50 },
            _method: 'put'
        }
    }).done(function( msg )
            {
                alert( "Data Saved: " + msg );
            });
```

Server:

"resource%5Bpos_y%5D=45&resource%5Bpos_x%5D=50&***method=put***&=1344004390840"

```
Started GET "/resources/35?resource%5Bpos_y%5D=45&resource%5Bpos_x%5D=50&_method=put&_=1344004390840" for 192.168.1.89 at 2012-08-03 16:33:10 +0200
Processing by ResourcesController#show as */*
  Parameters: {"resource"=>{"pos_y"=>"45", "pos_x"=>"50"}, "_"=>"1344004390840", "id"=>"35"}
  User Load (0.3ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" 
  Resource Load (0.1ms)  SELECT "resources".* FROM "resources" WHERE "resources"."id" = ? LIMIT 1  [["id", "35"]]
  Rendered resources/show.html.erb within layouts/login (0.8ms)
Completed 200 OK in 93ms (Views: 90.5ms | ActiveRecord: 0.4ms)
```

I'd appreciate any help.

Comment: Did you mean POST, not PUT? ....

Comment: I updated my answer. You could try that :-)

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Rails determines the put request via the parameter _method with the value 'put'.

As not all the browsers support the put method, rails cheats in the form_tag. its putting this output in a PUT form:

```
<input type='hidden' name='_method' value='put'>
```

So what you have to do is this:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    dataType: "script",
    url: '/resources/35',
    contentType: 'application/json',
    data: JSON.stringify({ resource:{pos_y:45,pos_x:50}, _method:'put' })
}).done(function( msg )
        {
            alert( "Data Saved: " + msg );
        });
```

Comment: hey that works great. Can you explain to me why we're converting the hash to a JSON string? `JSON.stringify`