# Mark when the user starts typing in a form

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ajax, jquery

I want to add the user to a post's `author` list when the user starts typing in a form.

For example, when the user types any letter (or press the 'enter' button) in the form, I would call `@post.authors.create(user_id: current_user.id)` to add the user to the list of authors of that specific post. I thought this would be impossible to implement, but using javascript to submit an ajax request might be sufficient to implement this method. Is it possible to achieve such method in a Rails application? If so, could anyone give me some directions?

Comment: You should listen for a [`keydown`](http://api.jquery.com/keydown/) event on your form. If it occurs use [`$.post`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/) to post the current user to your controller.

Comment: Is there a reason the user needs to be added as an author before they've actually submitted the form (presumably saving any changes)? I would think that the way you want to do it would be harder, and would potentially cause further complications for you, especially if the user were to delete any changes they made, or never actually save them. If you do need to do it, it should definitely be possible though.

Comment: Not a convention at all. If I just type here and don't hit "Add Comment", you could never see my comment.

Comment: I am very aware of the logic. It doesn't matter to me whether the user does not submit the form afterwards. I want to implement this function to let the users know that whether anyone(who will be added as the "author" temporarily) is editing a certain post.

Comment: @Mischa Could you explain a little more? I knew I had to listen to a `keydown` event, but had little knowledge about posting the current user to the controller.

Comment: @MaximusS Thanks for the bounty. It would have been nice if you had given the last details you need in the question. It would be nice if you could comment the answer whether the added route was required or not. Thx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For the following answer, I assume you are running Ruby on Rails with jQuery as javascript framework and have the current user (=author) logged in (i.e. the current user id in session). I'm explaining @Mischa's idea: Using the keypress event.

So, as you explained, you have a form to edit a post. I guess you have a textarea inside there with the post's text. For example `<textarea id="posting">This is a post</textarea>`.

Your next requirement was, to tell the server, "when the user types any letter (or press the 'enter' button) in the form". Hence we define an event handler, for the "keypress" event. This event handler should be removed, after the first key has been pressed. Thanks to @user2257149 for the following code (I adjusted it a little bit):

```
    function typeCatch(){
      $(this).off("keypress",typeCatch) // remove handler
      console.log("User start type");
    }

    $("#post").on("keypress",typeCatch); // add handler
```

This javascript code fragment **must** be below the definition of the `<textarea>`.

Now we have an event handler which is only fired once. In this handler, we trigger an ajax call to let the server know, the current user is editing the current post. As we're updating a specific attribute in the post object, we should trigger something like the following URL:

```
PUT http://www.example.com/posts/123/add_current_author
```

This means, we should use the HTTP *PUT* method to update the post with ID *123* and trigger method *add_current_author* in `PostsController`.

So we adjust the function `typeCatch()` to:

```
function typeCatch(){
  $(this).off("keypress",typeCatch)//remove handler
  $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: '/posts/123/add_current_author',
    data: JSON.stringify({_method: 'put'})
  });
}
```

(As most browsers don't support the PUT method, Ruby on Rails tricks that by sending the POST parameter "_method", I got this from @Michael Koper in his [answer to Ruby on rails - PUT method on update ajax](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11797425/1680187))

You might have to add this special route to Ruby on Rails (not sure about the following, my rails is a bit rusty):

```
resources :posts do
  collection do
    put "add_current_author"
  end
end
```

Now, in your `PostsController`, you have to define method `add_current_author`. I assume you instantiate `@post` to be the actual post (identified by given `:id`) in a `before_filter` and have your current user saved in `current_user`. So actually it should be as easy as:

```
def add_current_author
  @post.authors.create(user_id: current_user.id)
end
```

Though I must admit, it looks a bit weird (it's what you suggested). I guess, I'd have a 1:n connection between "posts" and "users" called "authors" and do the following:

```
@post.authors << current_user
```

Again: Thanks to @Micha, @user2257149 and @Michael Koper. I upvoted your answers.

**UPDATE:**
As stated in bounty comment, OP wants to change the current functionality from "mark read by user when shown" to "only mark as read, when user presses a key in comment form".

So currently `EssayController` has a `show` action like

```
def show
  ...
  @essay.reader_links.create(reader_id: current_user.id)
  ...
end
```

The given line should be removed, as current user should not be added when `@essay` shown. Furthermore, the `<textarea>` I defined above is the one in the comment form, so the HTML might look like

```
<html>
  ...
  <form action="essay/123/comment" method="post">
    ...
    <textarea name="comment_text" id="comment"></textarea>
    ...
  </form>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    function typeCatch() {
      ...
    }
    $("#post").on("keypress", typeCatch);
  </script>
</html>
```

Finally, action `add_current_author` should not be, as I assumed, in `PostController` but in `EssayController` and the route changed respectively.

**UPDATE 2:**
As @Yarek T stated, instead of `$("#post").on("keypress", typeCatch);` the jQuery function `one` can be used:

```
function typeCatch(){
  $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: '/posts/123/add_current_author',
    data: JSON.stringify({_method: 'put'})
  });
}
$("#post").one("keypress", typeCatch);
```

Answer (score 11):

You must make event handler for keypress and remove after first press.

```
function typeCatch(){
  $(this).off("keypress",typeCatch)//remove handler
  console.log("User start type");
}

$("$field_id").on("keypress",typeCatch)
```

Answer (score 1):

Has everyone forgot about jQuery's `$.one()` function? Its functionally the same as doing `$.on()` and then inside that `$.off()`.

Answer (score 0):

```
var flag = 0;
$(document).on('keypress', function(e) {
    if(flag == 0) {
         doSomething();
         flag = 1;
    }   
});
```