# RoutingError on ajax call to update fullcalendar event

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ajax, fullcalendar

i'm using [fullcalendar](http://fullcalendar.io/) to show events on my rails application. Works fine. Now i want the events to update in the database on drag and drop actions. For that i'm using [eventDrop](http://fullcalendar.io/docs/event_ui/eventDrop/) method and an ajax call based on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11797270/ruby-on-rails-put-method-on-update-ajax) answer:

```
eventDrop: function(event, delta, revertFunc) {
            update_source = update_prefix + event.user_id + "/appointments/" + event.id;
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                dataType: "script",
                url: update_source,
                contentType: 'application/json',
                data: JSON.stringify({ resource:{start:event.start, end: event.end}, _method:'put' })
            }).done(function( msg )
            {
                alert( "Data Saved: " + msg );
            });
        }
```

This is update method on the controller:

```
def update
  @appointment.update(appointment_params)
  if @appointment.save
    respond_to do |format|
      format.js
    end
  else
    render js: "alert('Please include phone number');"
  end
end
```

And these are the routes on rake routes:

```
PATCH  (/:locale)/companies/:company_id/users/:user_id/appointments/:id(.:format)      appointments#update
PUT    (/:locale)/companies/:company_id/users/:user_id/appointments/:id(.:format)      appointments#update
DELETE (/:locale)/companies/:company_id/users/:user_id/appointments/:id(.:format)      appointments#destroy
```

However i keep getting the following Error:

```
ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [POST] "/es/companies/1/users/50/appointments/140"):
```

Just in case; there is actually an appointment with id 140 belonging to a user 50 belonging to company 1 in the database.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changing your ajax request to `PUT` or `PATCH` will solve your issue, however I am not sure this is the intention. I mean:

```
        $.ajax({
            type: "PATCH",
            dataType: "script",
            url: update_source,
            contentType: 'application/json',
            data: { resource:{start:event.start, end: event.end} }
        }).done(function( msg )
        {
            alert( "Data Saved: " + msg );
        });
```

It will call `update` action. Also, you do not need `JSON.stringify`, just pass data `{...}`.

Comment: @ntonnelier can you pls guide me to achieve the same task??

Comment: hi @AnitaShalu, for me the issue was changing the action from POST to PATCH. You should try if that works.